# C# UWP - CSV in Datagrid

Tags: c#, gridview, uwp, datagridview, datagrid

I have been attempting to migrate my program from winForms to UWP as a learning exercise; I am new to C#.

In my winForms code I used:

```
private void BindData(string filePath)
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(filePath);
            if (lines.Length > 0)
            {
                //first line to create header
                globals.count = lines.Length;
                string firstLine = lines[0];
                string[] headerLabels = firstLine.Split(',');
                foreach (string headerWord in headerLabels)
                {
                    dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn(headerWord));
                }
                //For Data
                for (int i = 1; i < 100; i++)
                {
                    string[] dataWords = lines[i].Split(',');
                    DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
                    int columnIndex = 0;
                    foreach (string headerWord in headerLabels)
                    {
                        dr[headerWord] = dataWords[columnIndex++];
                    }
                    dt.Rows.Add(dr);
                }
          }
    }
```

How can I replicate this.
I have attempted following [this guide](http://matthiasshapiro.com/DisneyShorts/loading-csv-files-in-uwp) and [this guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2016/march/modern-apps-parsing-csv-files-in-uwp-apps)

Comment: Microsoft really should know better than to write such trash more than ten years after CSV had an RFC documenting it. i.e.: If you're trying to read CSV files line-by-line then you're doing it wrong. Please consult [RFC 4180 Common Format and MIME Type for Comma-Separated Values (CSV) Files](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4180) to get an understanding on the character-oriented streaming protocol that is CSV. Your first link that uses the CSVFileReader class is a much better example.

Answer (score 0):

> UWP - CSV in Datagrid

For loading csv data and display into DataGrid control, you could refer my previous case [reply](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56802894/7254781) that load the csv file and parse into DataGrid `ItemResource`. That reply contain the complete xaml and code behind.  Please note the csv file stored in the project folder. if the file stored in other location within your scenario, we suggest use [`FileOpenPicker`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/files/quickstart-using-file-and-folder-pickers) to access the csv file.

**Xaml Code**

```
    <controls:DataGrid
        x:Name="MyDataGrid"
        HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
        VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
        AlternatingRowBackground="Transparent"
        AlternatingRowForeground="Gray"
        AreRowDetailsFrozen="False"
        AreRowGroupHeadersFrozen="True"
        AutoGenerateColumns="False"
        CanUserReorderColumns="True"
        CanUserResizeColumns="True"
        CanUserSortColumns="False"
        ColumnHeaderHeight="32"
        FrozenColumnCount="0"
        GridLinesVisibility="None"
        HeadersVisibility="Column"
        HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"
        IsReadOnly="False"
        Loaded="DataGrid_Loaded"
        MaxColumnWidth="400"
        RowDetailsVisibilityMode="Collapsed"
        RowGroupHeaderPropertyNameAlternative="Range"
        SelectionMode="Extended"
        VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"
        >
        <controls:DataGrid.RowGroupHeaderStyles>
            <Style TargetType="controls:DataGridRowGroupHeader">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightGray" />
            </Style>
        </controls:DataGrid.RowGroupHeaderStyles>
    
        <controls:DataGrid.Columns>
            <controls:DataGridTextColumn
                Binding="{Binding Id}"
                Header="Id"
                Tag="Id"
                />
            <controls:DataGridTextColumn
                Binding="{Binding Title}"
                Header="Title"
                Tag="Title"
                />
            <controls:DataGridComboBoxColumn
                Binding="{Binding Link}"
                Header="Link"
                Tag="Link"
                />
            <controls:DataGridTextColumn
                Binding="{Binding Type}"
                Header="Type"
                Tag="Type"
                />
            <controls:DataGridTextColumn
                Binding="{Binding Remark}"
                Header="Remark"
                Tag="Remark"
                />
            <controls:DataGridTextColumn
                Binding="{Binding Time}"
                Header="Time"
                Tag="Time"
                />
        </controls:DataGrid.Columns>
    </controls:DataGrid>
```

**Model class**

```
    public class Item
    {
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string Link { get; set; }
        public string Type { get; set; }
        public string Remark { get; set; }
        public string Time { get; set; }
    }

**Data Process**

    private ObservableCollection<Item> Items;
    private void DataGrid_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        using (var reader = new StreamReader("Assets\\Archive.csv",true))
        using (var csv = new CsvReader(reader))
        {
            var records = csv.GetRecords<Item>();
            Items = new ObservableCollection<Item>(records);           
        }
    
        MyDataGrid.ItemsSource = Items;           
    }
```

Comment: That answer won't replicate the code above. It will require me to know what column headers and how many columns the file contains. That would make this program very difficult to operate.

Comment: I shared the sample code in my previous reply. For better understanding, I copied above, please check.